# Imported sqlite database is missing data and mixing columns

Tags: android, list, sqlite

I have put an sqlite database in my assets folder and imported it onto the phone.

I created an object with multiple properties and when I create a list of that object and assign each property a value from a column of the table they get mixed up

Below is my code

```
public ArrayList<Exercise> getExercisesFromQuery(String Query) {
    ArrayList<Exercise> ExerciseList = new ArrayList<Exercise>();

    Cursor cursor = mDb.rawQuery(Query, null);
    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Exercise e = new Exercise();
            e.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            e.setName(cursor.getString(1));
            e.setMuscle(cursor.getString(2));
            e.setDescription(cursor.getString(3));
            e.setFilepath(cursor.getString(4));
            e.setSets(cursor.getString(5));
            e.setReps(cursor.getString(6));
            e.setEquipment(cursor.getString(7));
            e.setPrimaryMuscle(cursor.getString(8));
            e.setSecondaryMuscle(cursor.getString(9));
            e.setDifficulty(cursor.getString(10));
            // Adding contact to list
            ExerciseList.add(e);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return ExerciseList;
}
```

The current problem is when I do `object.getName` it gives me the muscle and if I do `object.getmuscle` it is blank and there is no value but if I do `object.getDescription` it works fine.

It is not a problem with the database it works fine in any sqlite manager.

Any ideas as to what is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The reason why the columns are not being returned in the order you expect is not clear. They should come back in the order specified in your query or in the order they are on the table if you are doing SELECT *. However it is not really necessary to address that specific puzzle.

A more defensive and maintainable coding approach is to request each column's index from the cursor by using the getColumnIndexOrThrow method instead of hardcoding them. For example:

```
int ID_INDEX = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id");
int NAME_INDEX = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("name");
```

If the column doesn't exist you'll get an exception. If it does, you now have its index within the cursor which you can use in the calls to cursor.getString:

```
e.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(ID_INDEX)));
e.setName(cursor.getString(NAME_INDEX));
```

So you no longer need to worry about what order the columns come back in and you won't need to change any hardcoded index values if your query changes in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the columns in the database are in the correct order - column `Name` should be the second column, column `Muscle` should be the third column.

Comment: they are, and it still doesnt explain why the muscle column is completely blank

Comment: You should add a break point at the beginning of your `do` loop and see what values `cursor.getString(...)` returns to give you an idea.